# Logarithmic lenghts in plotting arrows with quiver-function from pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, logarithm

Is there an easy way to scale the lenghts of the arrows drawn by the quiver function from PyPlot logarithmically?

The reason is, that I plot wind arrows over the land and over the ocean, whereas the magnitude of the wind over the ocean is about ten times higher.

Therefore, either the arrows over the land are too small to get any information from plotting them, or the arrows over the ocean are that big that the plot is too crowded over the ocean.

I already tried to use a symlog function to make scale the data logarithmically but it seems like the angles make troubles. To emphasize this, here is the code for a small plot:

```
def main():
  lat, lon, u, v = readmulticol2Dfile('test.txt', shape=(9,6))
  # map without logarithmic scaling
  plt.subplot(1,2,1)
  mapproj = bm.Basemap(projection='cyl', llcrnrlon=lon.min(), urcrnrlon=lon.max(), llcrnrlat=lat.min(), urcrnrlat=lat.max())
  mapproj.drawcoastlines()
  mapproj.drawparallels(np.linspace(-20,20,5), labels=[1,0,0,0])
  mapproj.drawmeridians(np.linspace(-80,20,5), labels=[0,0,0,1])
  plt.title('linear')
  plt.quiver(lon, lat, u, v, color='k', units='x')
  # map with logarithmic scaling
  plt.subplot(1,2,2)
  mapproj = bm.Basemap(projection='cyl', llcrnrlon=lon.min(), urcrnrlon=lon.max(), llcrnrlat=lat.min(), urcrnrlat=lat.max())
  mapproj.drawcoastlines()
  mapproj.drawparallels(np.linspace(-20,20,5), labels=[1,0,0,0])
  mapproj.drawmeridians(np.linspace(-80,20,5), labels=[0,0,0,1])
  plt.quiver(lon, lat, symlog(u), symlog(v), color='k', units='x')
  plt.title('logarithmic')
  plt.show()

def readmulticol2Dfile(fname, header=True, delimiter='\t', shape=None):
  """reads a multicolumn txt-file and converts it to numpy arrays"""
  a=np.loadtxt(fname).T
  if shape is not None:
    b=[np.zeros(shape=shape)]*4
    for i in xrange(len(a)):    b[i]=np.reshape(a[i],shape)
    return b
  else: return a

def symlog(x):
  """ Returns the symmetric log10 value """
  return np.sign(x) * np.log10(np.abs(x))

if __name__=="__main__":
  main()
```

using this data, saved in `test.txt`

```
# lattitude longitude   u   v
2.145047503739818495e+01    -8.062500000000000000e+01   -5.790064811706542969e+00   2.341136932373046875e-01
2.145047503739818495e+01    -7.312500000000000000e+01   -7.119166374206542969e+00   -1.223894119262695312e+00
2.145047503739818495e+01    -6.562500000000000000e+01   -6.140162467956542969e+00   -1.082292556762695312e+00
2.145047503739818495e+01    -5.812500000000000000e+01   -4.589381217956542969e+00   2.853832244873046875e-01
2.145047503739818495e+01    -5.062500000000000000e+01   -5.221705436706542969e+00   4.221019744873046875e-01
2.145047503739818495e+01    -4.312500000000000000e+01   -5.333521842956542969e+00   6.321525573730468750e-02
1.771996152644742750e+01    -2.812500000000000000e+01   -7.793482780456542969e+00   -3.714616775512695312e+00
1.771996152644742750e+01    -2.062500000000000000e+01   -6.195338249206542969e+00   -6.160417556762695312e+00
1.585470386969487322e+01    -7.687500000000000000e+01   -8.054713249206542969e+00   -1.638355255126953125e-01
1.585470386969487322e+01    -6.937500000000000000e+01   -7.378443717956542969e+00   -2.906990051269531250e-02
1.585470386969487322e+01    -6.187500000000000000e+01   -6.270533561706542969e+00   3.127269744873046875e-01
1.585470386969487322e+01    -5.437500000000000000e+01   -7.410181999206542969e+00   -1.028003692626953125e-01
1.212418712345576566e+01    -3.937500000000000000e+01   -8.221217155456542969e+00   -2.800065994262695312e+00
1.212418712345576566e+01    -3.187500000000000000e+01   -7.579127311706542969e+00   -3.560319900512695312e+00
1.212418712345576566e+01    -2.437500000000000000e+01   -5.761256217956542969e+00   -5.112565994262695312e+00
1.025892816800637597e+01    -8.062500000000000000e+01   -4.789576530456542969e+00   -4.363542556762695312e+00
1.025892816800637597e+01    -7.312500000000000000e+01   -1.818385124206542969e+00   -1.677995681762695312e+00
1.025892816800637597e+01    -6.562500000000000000e+01   -3.078639030456542969e+00   -1.554460525512695312e+00
6.528409401479990493e+00    -5.062500000000000000e+01   -7.822779655456542969e+00   -1.683855056762695312e+00
6.528409401479990493e+00    -4.312500000000000000e+01   -8.200709342956542969e+00   -2.835222244262695312e+00
6.528409401479990493e+00    -3.562500000000000000e+01   -7.456568717956542969e+00   -2.850358963012695312e+00
6.528409401479990493e+00    -2.812500000000000000e+01   -5.878443717956542969e+00   -2.700944900512695312e+00
6.528409401479990493e+00    -2.062500000000000000e+01   -2.720240592956542969e+00   -1.258562088012695312e+00
4.663149706177883935e+00    -7.687500000000000000e+01   1.257298469543457031e+00    -1.143815994262695312e+00
9.326299678379910141e-01    -6.187500000000000000e+01   -6.386976242065429688e-01   -2.507495880126953125e-01
9.326299678379910141e-01    -5.437500000000000000e+01   -2.149439811706542969e+00   -1.390886306762695312e+00
9.326299678379910141e-01    -4.687500000000000000e+01   -5.939478874206542969e+00   -1.460222244262695312e+00
9.326299678379910141e-01    -3.937500000000000000e+01   -6.882838249206542969e+00   -5.959644317626953125e-01
9.326299678379910141e-01    -3.187500000000000000e+01   -6.343287467956542969e+00   -1.565113067626953125e-01
9.326299678379910141e-01    -2.437500000000000000e+01   -5.749537467956542969e+00   3.444652557373046875e-01
-4.663149706177883935e+00   -7.312500000000000000e+01   -7.033824920654296875e-02   -3.654956817626953125e-01
-4.663149706177883935e+00   -6.562500000000000000e+01   -5.674085617065429688e-01   -3.176441192626953125e-01
-4.663149706177883935e+00   -5.812500000000000000e+01   -1.063014030456542969e+00   -1.213550567626953125e-01
-4.663149706177883935e+00   -5.062500000000000000e+01   -1.417994499206542969e+00   -2.028980255126953125e-01
-4.663149706177883935e+00   -4.312500000000000000e+01   -1.486842155456542969e+00   -8.557300567626953125e-01
-4.663149706177883935e+00   -3.562500000000000000e+01   -5.729517936706542969e+00   1.451887130737304688e+00
-8.393668907692383385e+00   -2.062500000000000000e+01   -6.579615592956542969e+00   2.450422286987304688e+00
-1.025892816800637597e+01   -7.687500000000000000e+01   4.018297195434570312e-01    -1.755542755126953125e-01
-1.025892816800637597e+01   -6.937500000000000000e+01   2.187242507934570312e-01    -5.783863067626953125e-01
-1.025892816800637597e+01   -6.187500000000000000e+01   -3.462171554565429688e-01   -8.737964630126953125e-01
-1.025892816800637597e+01   -5.437500000000000000e+01   -4.731702804565429688e-01   -3.200855255126953125e-01
-1.025892816800637597e+01   -4.687500000000000000e+01   -8.545179367065429688e-01   -4.890308380126953125e-01
-1.398944571235667311e+01   -3.187500000000000000e+01   -7.993678092956542969e+00   1.462230682373046875e-01
-1.398944571235667311e+01   -2.437500000000000000e+01   -8.063502311706542969e+00   1.512434005737304688e+00
-1.585470386969487322e+01   -8.062500000000000000e+01   -2.528346061706542969e+00   3.198469161987304688e+00
-1.585470386969487322e+01   -7.312500000000000000e+01   2.924547195434570312e-01    1.297590255737304688e+00
-1.585470386969487322e+01   -6.562500000000000000e+01   -3.598890304565429688e-01   -1.232194900512695312e+00
-1.585470386969487322e+01   -5.812500000000000000e+01   4.196643829345703125e-02    -1.524187088012695312e+00
-1.958521860882233057e+01   -4.312500000000000000e+01   -1.116724967956542969e+00   -3.195972442626953125e-01
-1.958521860882233057e+01   -3.562500000000000000e+01   -5.567896842956542969e+00   -3.761003494262695312e+00
-1.958521860882233057e+01   -2.812500000000000000e+01   -7.378443717956542969e+00   -1.043718338012695312e+00
-1.958521860882233057e+01   -2.062500000000000000e+01   -8.015162467956542969e+00   7.102775573730468750e-02
-2.145047503739818495e+01   -7.687500000000000000e+01   2.352025032043457031e+00    2.376691818237304688e+00
-2.145047503739818495e+01   -6.937500000000000000e+01   2.939915657043457031e+00    1.054914474487304688e+00
```

But unfortunately the result looks quite strange. The lenghts are in fact logarithmic but the angles behave strange in some regions.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance =)

PS: I have not enough reputation to add a figure or a second hyperlink here so I uploaded it on the ftp-server where it will be automatically removed after two weeks. You can simply access the figure by replacing the '.txt' by '.png' in the datalink above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gather you could just scale the arrow lengths before passing them in. Here is an example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def symlog(x):
    """ Returns the symmetric log10 value """
    return np.sign(x) * np.log10(np.abs(x))

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10,5))

# Generate fake data
N = 50
X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 1, N), np.linspace(0, 1, N))
U = np.random.normal(0, 0.2, size=(50, 50))
V = np.random.normal(0, 0.2, size=(50, 50))

# Set RHS data to be larger than LHS
U[:, N/2:] *= 1000
V[:, N/2:] *= 1000
angles=np.arctan2(V,U)*180.0/np.pi # calculate angles manually

#Without scaling
HEAD_LENGTH = 4
Q = ax1.quiver( X[::3, ::3], Y[::3, ::3], U[::3, ::3], V[::3, ::3],
             color='k', units='x', headaxislength=HEAD_LENGTH)

#With scaling
Q = ax2.quiver( X[::3, ::3], Y[::3, ::3], symlog(U[::3, ::3]), symlog(V[::3, ::3]),
             color='k', units='x', headaxislength=HEAD_LENGTH, angles=angles)

plt.show()
```

[image]

On the left is shown the raw data while on the right I have scaled the arrow lengths using `symlog()`. This scales the magnitude of the values while retaining their sign otherwise you will have errors logging negative numbers.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help! :) Although it worked for you, the logarithims seems to cause troubles with the angles. I editted my post with an example using the simlog function (see above). Can you reproduce my problem using my data and script?

Comment: I doubt it as I don't have your data file. Please add a short conplete working example e.g that will copy and paste producing plots. This will help improve the answers you get.

Comment: Okay, I made it by calculating the angles manually and using the keyword 'angles' of the quiver plot. I provide the full code below.

Answer (score 1):

I used a similar approach to Greg when I encountered this issue, but the problem with his adjustments to the vector, as you noticed, is that they don't retain the direction of the arrows. To do this, you need to adjust U and V in your code by the same factors as follows:

```
def transform(u, v):
    arrow_lengths = np.sqrt(u*u + v*v)
    len_adjust_factor = np.log10(arrow_lengths + 1) / arrow_lengths
    return u*len_adjust_factor, v*len_adjust_factor

U2, V2 = transform(U, V)
```

This adjustment only alters the lengths of the arrows so that the new lengths are log10 of the old lengths.

Note: I use log10(x+1) as opposed to log10(x) just so that the function does not change the sign of the output relative to the input, and so that the function starts at the point (0,0).